# How to prevent data loss on a non concurrent data structure/ object?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, apache-commons

I'm trying to use [Apache's descriptive statistics](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6.1/index.html) to calculate a moving average. The idea is that multiple threads will be adding values to this object and, every minute another thread calculates the average and other statistics (and empties the object).

Because the number of threads and the high frequency (each thread writes every second) I'm worried that data will be lost if I just use

```
synchronized(descriptiveStatistic) {
}
```

every time I want to access it.

What would be the best way to work around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of emptying the statistics object I would replace it, i.e. start with a fresh instance to gather new statistics (if that's actually what you need - why would you empty the statistics in the first place)? Additionally you might have a look at `SynchronizedDescriptiveStatistics` which would be the thread-safe alternative to `DescriptiveStatistics`. Would that already help? If not you might want to elaborate on your requirements, e.g. what kind of concurrency you need.

Comment: Thank you @Thomas , this was really helpful. I don't know how I missed SynchronizedDescriptiveStatistics. I need to empty the statistics as a reset that is needed every minute (save into a database the minute average for example). Replacing the object is a great idea tyty!